# Primary and irreducible ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, monomial-ideals

> I have to verify that the ideal $I = \langle x^3,x^2y,xy^3,y^5\rangle \subset R=\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ is primary. I then have to go on to show that it is not irreducible by writing it as an intersection of two larger ideals.

Now I have a definition of primary but I am not sure how to actually show that for $f,g \in R$ that if $fg \in I$ then $f \in I$ or $g^m \in I$ for some $m>0$. I am also confused as to how I should reduce the ideal, as I'm not familiar with the process of finding $I_1, I_2$ such that $ I = I_1 \cap I_2$ although I understand it has something to do with splitting products, but is it true that, for instance, $I = <x^3,x^2,xy^3,y^5> \cap <x^3,y,xy^3,y^5> $ for instance?

Answer (score 1):

$\langle x^3,\underline{x^2y},xy^3,y^5\rangle=\langle x^3,{\color{red}{x^2}},xy^3,y^5\rangle\cap \langle x^3,{\color{red}y},xy^3,y^5\rangle=\langle x^2,\underline{xy^3},y^5\rangle\cap \langle x^3,y\rangle\ (\text{for reducibility you can stop here!})=\langle x^2,{\color{red}x},y^5\rangle\cap\langle x^2,{\color{red}{y^3}},y^5\rangle\cap \langle x^3,y\rangle=\langle x,y^5\rangle\cap\langle x^2,y^3\rangle\cap \langle x^3,y\rangle$

It follows that $I$ is an intersection of three $(x,y)$-primary ideals, so $I$ is primary and is not irreducible.

**Remark.** If you want to prove directly that your ideal is primary, then notice that $\sqrt I=(x,y)$ which is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb C[x,y]$.

Answer (score 0):

It is not irreducible.
page.9 of *Herzog-Hibi*'s book, "*Monomial Ideals*", has:

> [Corollary $1.3.2$](http://books.google.com/books?id=3PxzYIBTibsC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=Corollary%201.3.2&f=false). A monomial ideal is irreducible if and only if it is generated
>   by pure powers of the variables.

After proof, by an example, (1.3.3), they illustrate the procedure. **It is very helpful**.